# Obtain $ \sum\limits_{\substack{i}}^{} \mathbf{N}(x_{i}) $ from $ \sum\limits_{\substack{i}}^{} \dfrac{1}{\mathbf{N}(x_{i})},$

Tags: calculus, probability, sequences-and-series, probability-theory

Is it possible to obtain $  \sum\limits_{\substack{i}}^{} \mathbf{N}(x_{i}) $ from $ \sum\limits_{\substack{i}}^{} \dfrac{1}{\mathbf{N}(x_{i})},$

where, $\mathbf{N}(x_{i})=Y+1$ is a random variable with $Y \sim Bin(n-1, r_{n}).$

The variables $\mathbf{N}(x_{i})$ for $i=1..n$ are not independent.

Comment: What is $\mathbf{N}$?

Comment: Sorry, I did a mistake. I edited the question.

Comment: Is the distribution of $\mathbf{N}$ known? Otherwise we may only be able to obtain an estimate via the HM-AM-GM inequalities.

Comment: Yes, it is a binomially distributed (a modified distribution because I know that the random variable will never take 0 as a value). But the variables are not independent.

Comment: You should write all details in the question itself and not in comments.